# How to make character that can be dissolved

Tags: modeling, rigging, unity

I'm making robot for my game in Unity. Robot is based on human body and it is also rigged. Main problem is that I want to dissolve parts of the robot when it's shot, but only arms and legs.. And for example when it is shot to left leg, only left leg is dissolved and body is intact.

So model structure in unity should look like body, left arm, right arm, left leg, right leg.

Anyone can help what's the best way how to do this and rigging part?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I think I have figured it out. Just separate the model to make objects of body parts. Rigging still works.